# jQuery FancyBox not working after altering DOM

Tags: jquery, dom, fancybox

We are using [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/home) to provide a lightbox for our image gallery.

We have a ul with class 'images'.  Each list item contains an anchor tag and an image inside of it.  The anchor tag contains an href of the full sized image.

This code is used to set up the lightbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (!themeJSEnabled) {
            $(".images a").fancybox({
                'transitionIn': 'elastic',
                'transitionOut': 'elastic',
                'titlePosition': 'inside',
                'autoScale': true,
                'centerOnScroll': true,
                'overlayOpacity': .95,
                'titleFromAlt': true,
                'scrolling': 'no'
            });
        }
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

This works fine for most of our private labels, but one particular style doesn't work.

The style that doesn't work uses javascript to rip apart part of the DOM and reconstruct it (as follows)

```
 $("#subcontent2").before("<div class='combinedContentWrapper'></div>");
 $("div.combinedContentWrapper").append("<div class='combinedContent'></div>");
 $("div.combinedContent").append("<div class='sc1'></div>");
 $("div.combinedContent").append("<div class='mc'></div>");
 $("div.mc").append($(".maincontent").html());
 $("div.sc1").append($(".subcontent1").html());
 $("div.maincontent").remove();
 $("div.subcontent1").remove();
 $("div.mc").addClass("maincontent");
 $("div.sc1").addClass("subcontent1");
```

In themes of this style themeJSEnabled (from the first code block) is true, so AFTER the DOM is reconstructed with the above code, I use the following code to register the Fancybox:

```
 $(".images a").fancybox({
      'transitionIn': 'elastic',
      'transitionOut': 'elastic',
      'titlePosition': 'inside',
      'autoScale': true,
      'centerOnScroll': true,
      'overlayOpacity': .95,
      'titleFromAlt': true,
      'scrolling': 'no'
  });
```

As I understand it, this should work, as I didn't register anything before the DOM was reconstructed, and the fancybox should be registering on the new elements.

However, when I first click any image in the list, it throws a javascript error - 't is undefined'.  This error is listed as being on line 17, within a completely unrelated method.  The error still occurs even if that method is surrounded by a try/catch block.  The error does NOT occur on subsequent clicks on images, which product no result.

What can I do to get the Fancybox to work in this situation?

You can see an example live on our test server at [this link](http://paradise.test.mem.com/ContentDisplay.aspx?ID=33375747).  Click on 'Images', then click an image.

Comment: My first guess is that your DOM manipulation has screwed up your HTML somehow.  Have you looked at the DOM elements in the console to see if everything is in the right place?  I'm thinking that you overwrote part of your JavaScript when you altered the DOM.  Although without seeing a demo page, I'm not sure how you're going to get a good answer.

Comment: @Sparky672: the DOM manipulation hasn't changed the HTML of the UL or nested elements, and the javascript I listed above runs.

Comment: If it's causing an error then the Fancybox behaviour is being attached. Is the error coming from Fancybox code or your own? At a guess (with no demo to see what all those functions are doing) the Fancybox code is being attached on page load, then you remove the elements, breaking the Fancybox, and reattaching it just causes confusion. Try working out what's calling the unrelated function, and when.

Comment: @Blowski, I've included a link to a demo on our test server.

Comment: `</img>` tags are not valid HTML for your chosen `Doctype`.  For your `Doctype`, `<img>` tags should be self-closed by using `/>`.  Also, since the Javascript error is flagged as coming from the Google Analytics code, simply remove the Google Analytics code as a test to see if it starts working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, we eventually found the cause.

When we modify the DOM, it seems to lose the references to the fancybox javascript.

This was fixed by moving the fancybox references to the head as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.Page, GetType(), "fancybox1", "scripts/FancyBox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js");
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.Page, GetType(), "fancybox2", "scripts/FancyBox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js");
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"scripts/FancyBox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css\" />"));
}
```

Once we did this, it started working for us.

Comment: LOL... my first comment back on 12/22:  _"My first guess is that your DOM manipulation has screwed up your HTML somehow."_  Anyway, glad you figured it out.